# What is the best practice for using two namespaces in a single file for backwards compatibility?

Tags: php, namespaces

I need to refactor a PHP project where the vendor has undergone a re-brand. The project currently uses the namespace `OldCompany`, and I need to change this to `NewCompany`, however I've realized I need to keep the old namespace for backwards compatibility, in the cases where existing users are using `try {} catch (/OldCompany/Exception $e) {}`... If I simply change the namespace to `NewCompany`, I will break their integration if they upgrade SDK versions straight up. After reading the [PHP Namespace docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php), I tried the method outlined in Example #3, and modified all of my files like this:

```
<?
namespace NewCompany{ /* no namespace-specific code needed */ };
namespace OldCompany{ /* no namespace-specific code needed */ };

namespace {
    /* global namespace code. code that applies to both namespaces? */
    
    require_once('file1.php');
    require_once('file2.php');

    /* classes and functions within the global namespace */

}
```

The above throws a PHP Fatal Exception and can't find the `NewCompany` namespace.

I definitely do not want to duplicate code as per Example #2 of the [docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php), since there isn't namespace-specific code.

What is the best way to preserve the existing namespace of `OldCompany` for existing users while refactoring a re-brand to `NewCompany' for new users?  Should I be looking for a different solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Leaving in the old namespace doesn't *really* make the code have the new one with the new company name does it? IMO either just stick with the old company name, or refactor it all. "How" depends on how big your code base is, do you have testing in place so can change whatever and just run tests to check nothing is broken?

Comment: @James Thanks for replying. The code base is relatively small as it's simply a wrapper for the vendor's small REST API. (~10 classes/files, ~15 exposed methods); I do have tests in place, so that shouldn't be an issue. I'd just really like to avoid forcing users to update their existing codebase as it would require additional dev/qa effort on their part. 

I feel my answer lies somewhere within the `use` operator ([docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)) but I'm unable to grasp if that is what I actually need from the Importing/Aliasing examples provided.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> namespace NewCompany{ /* no namespace-specific code needed */ };
> namespace OldCompany{ /* no namespace-specific code needed */ };
> ```

This is *setting* namespaces. But surely your issue is old vendor namespace has changed to a new one? This means you need to import (`use`) the new namespace instead of the old one?

Maybe I've misunderstood you, but are you confused about the difference between setting and importing namespaces? If the vendor has changed to a new namespace then you need to import the new one, rather than the old one. But this has nothing to do with setting namespaces.

> I definitely do not want to duplicate code as per Example #2 of the
>   docs, since there isn't namespace-specific code.

If there's no namespace specific code then what problem are you trying to resolve?

> I need to keep the old namespace for backwards
>   compatibility, in the cases where existing users are using 
>   `try {} catch (/OldCompany/Exception $e) {}`.

Surely whatever namespace they have in their end won't affect your side of things? So you could update all your code's namespaces and not worry about what they use? They just call your endpoint or whatever as normal?

Perhaps be more specific about that if it's a real issue somehow.

It sounds to me like you just need to update your import statements for the vendor's new namespace.

---

Something else to consider is refactor how you manage vendors.

I presume you are not using a pre-made framework, such as Symfony (they have predetermined ways of managing vendors and things).

The fact you are considering refactoring throughout your code rather than a *single* config file (or whatever) makes me think your code has a design flaw. As it seems you are changing code (namespace) within your class files based on a 3rd party company (vendor) changing *their* name.  And where possible your code should be entirely abstract from such changes to this degree.

I suggest considering abstracting things out into centralised places whenever it makes sense. This allows the one centralised thing to be altered and changes just automatically ripple down to all your code without any need for a huge refactor.

You could make your own generic names for your vendors so whatever they call themselves doesn't matter in your code.

E.g. vendor `FunkyJoesEmailer` in your app will just be `Emailer`. Then *whichever* emailer library you decide to use now and in the future will be in the same `Emailer` DIR and namespaces won't change, always be `Whatever\Emailer`.

Then in some file high up the load chain you'd have some wrapper class (or service or container like thing) which would load `FunkyJoesEmailer` in whatever namespace that is in via your generic name, such as `$this->Emailer`. So in your code you'd call on `$this->Emailer` which would return an instance of whatever emailer (vendor) you are using.

If you ever needed to do a namespace change or even entirely swap out the Emailer vendor you use, the change is in one place and would ripple down in your code because it's still `$this->Emailer`.

While this approach doesn't resolve your having to change everything now, it does mean you only ever have to change it this once. Then in the future can just replace vendors or let their renaming happen within their code and your path (namespace) to it remains the same.